# failures for Google Apps Script

Tags: copy, google-apps-script

Your script, Copy of Send SMS - Techawakening.org, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.

The script is used by the document Copy of Get Free SMS alerts for New Incoming Emails on Gmail - Techawakening.org.

Summary:
Error Message   Count
Authorization is required to perform that action.   1024

I have received email like this
Do i have to authorize every time?

Answer (score 0):

You have to (re-)authorize every time when you change the script. If you don't touch it, then the authorization will be saved and the set-up triggers run properly.